# ANTLR calculator with negative numbers support

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to create a calculator that supports also negative numbers, and create in the end a lisp-style tree.

I define the lexer rules like this :

```
INT :'-'? [0-9]+ ;
LBRACKET :  '(';
RBRACKET :  ')';
MULTIPLICATION : '*' ;
DIVISION: '/' ;
PLUS: '+' ;
MINUS: '-' ;
```

And I have a rule for each operation, for example:

```
 e13=exp MINUS e14=exp{
SPTree tempTree= new SPTree("-");
tempTree.insertChild($e13.tree);
tempTree.insertChild($e14.tree);
$tree=tempTree;
}
```

But when I'm trying to enter the expression: `2-3` the lisp tree that comes out is `(2)`.

Why does it ignore `-3`?

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* define `INT` as supporting negative numbers. Leave that to the subtraction operator.

Right now, the following input:

```
2-3
```

Will be tokenized like this: `2` `-3`, which is: `INT` `INT`. And you didn't define a parser rule that is able to handle that.

If you drop that `'-'?` from the `INT` definition, you'll get the expected result:
`2` `-` `3`, which is `INT` `MINUS` `INT`, and that is parsable.

So, just define the following:

```
INT : [0-9]+ ;
```

Additionally, you should add a required `EOF` to the root parser rule, so the parser will generate an error on unexpected additional input.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29996191/3764814) for a simple working math example.

Comment: Through that way 2 - 3 is working but -3 + 2 isn't.
Why?
it print 5 as a result, ignoring the minus.

Comment: @SctALE this should work fine, you must have an issue with your rules (there are no parser rules in the question). See my linked answer which works fine, and it that doesn't help you, post a new question along with your code. You probably didn't include an unary minus rule.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267834/antlr-parsing-and-code-generation-with-operator-and-number-sign Should I write  something more to help understanding my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negation expression , not a negation number. For example :

```
additiveExpr 
    :   multExpr (('+' |'-' ) multExpr )*;  
multExpr 
    :   negationExpr (('*' |'/' ) negationExpr )*; 
negationExpr 
    :   ('-')? primary; 
primary  
    :   atom           
    |  '(' orExpr ')';
```