# ANTLR: minus expression precedence and different results with Grun

Tags: java, antlr4, operator-precedence

I have a grammar like this:

```
/* entry point */
parse: expr EOF;


expr
    : value                                 # argumentArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=(MULT|DIV) r=expr     # multdivArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=(PLUS|MINUS) r=expr   # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | operator=('-'|'+') r=expr             # minusPlusArithmeticExpr
    | IDENTIFIER '(' (expr ( COMMA  expr )* ) ? ')'# functionExpr
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN                    # parensArithmeticExpr
    ;

value
    : number
    | variable
    | string // contains date
    | bool
    | null_value
    ;


/* Atomes */

bool
    : BOOL
    ;

variable
    : VARIABLE
    ;

string
    : STRING_LITERAL
    ;


number
    : ('+'|'-')? NUMERIC_LITERAL
    ;

null_value
    : NULL // TODO: test this
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*
    ;

NUMERIC_LITERAL
    : DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT* )? ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )? // ex: 0.05e3
    | '.' DIGIT+ ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )? // ex: .05e3
    ;

INT: DIGIT+;

STRING_LITERAL
    :  '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
    |  '"' ( ~'"' | '""' )* '"'
    ;

VARIABLE
    : LBRACKET ( ~']' | ' ')* RBRACKET
    ;
```

Now, I want to parse this:

```
-1.3 * 5 + -2 * 7
```

With Grun, I get this:

```
 antlr4 formula.g4 && javac *.java && time  grun formula parse -gui
 -1.3*5 + -2*7
 ^D
```

[image]

Which looks OK and I would be happy with that.

But in my Java code, I get called like this using the Visitor pattern:

```
visitMinusPlusArithmeticExpr -1.3*5+-2*7 // ugh ?? sees "- (1.3 * 5 + - 2 * 7 )" instead of "(-1.3*5) + (-2*7)"
visitAddsubtArithmeticExpr 1.3*5+-2*7
visitMultdivArithmeticExpr 1.3*5
visitArgumentArithmeticExpr 1.3
visitNumber 1.3
visitArgumentArithmeticExpr 5
visitValue 5
visitNumber 5
visitMinusPlusArithmeticExpr -2*7 // UHG? should see a MultDiv with -2 and 7
visitMultdivArithmeticExpr 2*7
visitArgumentArithmeticExpr 2
visitValue 2
visitNumber 2
visitArgumentArithmeticExpr 7
visitValue 7
visitNumber 7
```

Which means that I don't get my negative number (-1.3), but rather the 'minus expression', which I should not get.

Why is my Java result different from Grun ? I have verified that the grammar is recompiled and I use my parser like this:

```
    formulaLexer   lexer = new formulaLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(s));
    formulaParser parser = new formulaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

    parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);
    parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy()); // will throw exceptions on failure

    formula = tryParse(parser);
    if( formula == null && errors.isEmpty() ){
        // the parsing failed, retry in LL mode
        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
        parser.reset();
        tryParse(parser);
    }
```

I have disabled the SLL mode to verify if this was not the problem, and the result was the same.
I thought this could be a problem of precedence, but in my `expr` I have specified to match a `value` first, and then only a `minusPlusArithmeticExpr`.

I can't understand how I will detect this 'minus' expression instead of my 'negative value'. Can you check this?

Also, why does Grun show the correct behavior and not my Java code?

#### EDIT

Following the comments advice, I modified the grammar to look like this:

```
expr
    : value                                 # argumentArithmeticExpr
    | (PLUS|MINUS) expr                     # plusMinusExpr
    | l=expr operator=(MULT|DIV) r=expr     # multdivArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=(PLUS|MINUS) r=expr   # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | function=IDENTIFIER '(' (expr ( COMMA  expr )* ) ? ')'# functionExpr
    | '(' expr ')'           # parensArithmeticExpr
    ;
```

But now, I want to optimize the case where I have a single "-1.3" somewhere.
I don't know how to do it correctly, since when I land in the `visitMinusPlusAritmeticExpr`, I have to check if the terminal node is a number.

Here is what I get while debugging:

```
ctx = {formulaParser$PlusMinusExprContext@929} "[16]"
children = {ArrayList@955}  size = 2
    0 = {TerminalNodeImpl@962} "-"
    1 = {formulaParser$ArgumentArithmeticExprContext@963} "[21 16]" 
        children = {ArrayList@967}  size = 1
        0 = {formulaParser$ValueContext@990} "[22 21 16]"
            children = {ArrayList@992}  size = 1
            0 = {formulaParser$NumberContext@997} "[53 22 21 16]"
                children = {ArrayList@999}  size = 1
                0 = {TerminalNodeImpl@1004} "1.3"
```

I suspect I should walk down the tree and tell if the terminal node is a number, but it seems cumbersome. Do you have any idea on how to do that without compromising legibility of my code?

Comment: I cant tell you exact answer as i didn't play antlr for ages, but i think problem is because this statement your grammar  `expr : ('-'|'+') expr`  this together with statement `number  : ('+'|'-')? NUMERIC_LITERAL` make statement `-1` ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah I get what you say, but how should I do then? Because I should be able to identify "-1.3" and "-(5*6)" as two different things: the first is a negative number, the other is the operation or negating the expression in parenthesis.

Comment: yes "-1.3" and "-(5*6)"  are different, because have brackets, maybe that you should add, and make statement `expr : ('-'|'+') '(' expr ')'` in this case `-1` wont be ambiguous  and -5*6 wont be interpret as -(5*6)

Comment: Yes, typing my answer, I thought about that. But now my problem is that there are expressions that don't need parenthesis, like `-myvar`.

Comment: Also, why does the TestRig gets it correctly and my code does not??

Comment: you could do same with variable what you did with number `variable
    : ('+'|'-') VARIABLE` then -myvar will be evaluated properly. I don't have any clue why Grun gives you different result, maybe one of them is using bottom-up parsing while other top-down parsing

Comment: Get rid of the `('+'|'-')?` in the `number` rule. Negative number = negated positive number expression. I have a minimalist example grammar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29996191/3764814), along with a working calculator.

Comment: No that is not what I want. I should be able to detect whether the number is a negative one, so that I can optimize the case..

Comment: Yes, you should do it like Lucas suggested. If you want to detect if `expr` in `minusPlusArithmeticExpr` is a number, you simply do so in a visitor (check if `expr` is a `TerminalNode`)

Comment: Hi bart, I tried but in my debugger, I get a hierarchy like this in expr(): argumentArithmeticExpr -> value -> number -> terminalNode. So if I want to be sure of the type of the expr() I have to recursively check that I only have 1 child down to the bottom, and that the terminalNode is a number? This seems overly complicated.. Do you have a code example for that? Thanks for all the help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those interested, Lucas and Bart got the answer, and my implementation is like this:

```
expr
    : value                                 # argumentArithmeticExpr
    | (PLUS|MINUS) expr                     # plusMinusExpr
    | l=expr operator=(MULT|DIV) r=expr     # multdivArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=(PLUS|MINUS) r=expr   # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | function=IDENTIFIER '(' (expr ( COMMA  expr )* ) ? ')'# functionExpr
    | '(' expr ')'           # parensArithmeticExpr
    ;
```

And in the visitor of plusMinusExpr:

```
@Override
public Formula visitPlusMinusExpr(formulaParser.PlusMinusExprContext ctx) {
    if( debug ) LOG.log(Level.INFO, "visitPlusMinusExpr " + ctx.getText());
    Formula formulaExpr = visit(ctx.expr());
    if( ctx.MINUS() == null ) return formulaExpr;
    else {
        if(formulaExpr instanceof DoubleFormula){
            // optimization for numeric values: we don't return "(0.0 MINUS THEVALUE)" but directly "-THEVALUE"
            Double v = - ((DoubleFormula) formulaExpr).getValue();
            return new DoubleFormula( v );
        } else {
            return ArithmeticOperator.MINUS( 0, formulaExpr);
        }
    }
}
```