# tokenizing mathematical equation using regex

Tags: .net, regex, tokenize, evaluation

I'm trying to split up an equation string into tokens. Ive found a good starting point '([A-Za-z]+|[0-9.]+|[&=><\|!]+|\S)'.
However this has trouble with negative numbers:

```
turns: '5--4=sin(2+3)'
into: ['5','-','-','4','=','sin','(','2','+','3',')']
want: ['5','-','-4','=','sin','(','2','+','3',')']
```

and also

```
turns: -3+3
into: ['-','3','+','3']
want: ['-3','+','3']
```

It looks like a my regex could use something that checks if there is a number to the left of the '-' if not keep it with the next number(note '-3' has nothing to the left). Can it be done using regex? Or is there a better tool to split this up in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not powerful enough to do what you want in all contexts. Although you can make regex recognize `+` or `-` as part of an integer literal, for example, by adding an optional `[+-]?` in front of a digit sequence, the resultant regex would opt to tokenize `'-3+3'` as `['-3', '+3']` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1q02Hg/1)).

Using a lexer generator should fix this problem; alternatively, you can deal with "bundling" unary operators with their operands in the *parser*.

Comment: Oh come on, regex is perfectly suited for lexing - it's a Chomsky type 3 problem. OP doesn't realize that the result he got is actually *exactly* what he needs. in `-` `3`, the `-` is actually the unary negation operator.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Of course, regex is perfectly suited for lexing, but OP wants his lexing to be context-sensitive. He wants two minuses in `-3-3` treated differently, which is neither what he wants nor what regex can deliver.

Comment: Yes, after reading your answer for a second time now I get what you meant. BTW a lexer generator won't just magically fix the "problem" either, most just use regex under the hood ;)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I had ANTLR 3 in mind: I remember it producing some nice "magic" for me in terms of lexing complex expressions. I think they do it by adding an extra layer on "smartness" top of regular expressions, though.

Comment: Hmmm... there's no such thing in ANTLR as far as I can tell. It lets you inject code into lexer expressions though by using inline blocks `{...}` or predicates `{...}?` (I don't remember if the v3 lexer used `{...}?` or `{...}?=>` though), so you can achieve custom magic that way.

Comment: Your answer confused me but Lucas made me google words Ive never hear and now what your saying makes sense. Mainly the word 'unary' made me realize i was already using that with sin(x) in a way. Now as I loop through my un-typed string tokens I peek at the previous token to see if its a number otherwise consider it unary. Thanks to both Lucas and dasblinkenlight. I will have to try out Lucas's code when I get a chance.

Comment: Something like `((?<!^|[\-\+])[\-\+]|[\-\+]\d|[!<>]?=|\w+|.)` could work (if spaces are truncated).

Answer (score 2):

You are not approaching the problem correctly. The result you actually got *is* the correct one.

`-3+3` should parse to:

```
operator binary +
|
+-- operator unary -
|   |
|   +-- 3
|
+-- 3
```

It *will* be much easier to reason about math expressions this way, you'll avoid *many* ambiguities. Let just `-` always be a token on its own, and use it either as a binary minus, or an unary negation operator.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971097/how-to-create-ast-with-antlr4/29996191#29996191) for a related answer of mine which approaches the problem this way (it uses ANTLR but the lexing pass does exactly what I'm advising you to do).