# ANTLR4 AST Creation - How to create an AstVistor

Tags: java, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

With the help of this SO question [How to create AST with ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971097/how-to-create-ast-with-antlr4) I was able to create the AST Nodes, but I'm stuck at coding the `BuildAstVisitor` as depicted in the accepted answer's example.

I have a grammar that starts like this:

```
mini: (constDecl | varDef | funcDecl | funcDef)* ;
```

And I can neither assign a label to the block (antlr4 says `label X assigned to a block which is not a set`), and I have no idea how to visit the next node.

```
public Expr visitMini(MiniCppParser.MiniContext ctx) {
    return visitConstDecl(ctx.constDecl());
}
```

I have the following problems with the code above: I don't know how to decide whether it's a `constDecl`, `varDef` or any other option and `ctx.constDecl()` returns a `List<ConstDeclContext>` whereas I only need one element for the `visitConstDecl` function.

edit:

More grammar rules:

```
mini: (constDecl | varDef | funcDecl | funcDef)* ;

//--------------------------------------------------

constDecl:   'const' type ident=ID init ';' ;
init:        '=' ( value=BOOLEAN | sign=('+' | '-')? value=NUMBER ) ;
// ...

//--------------------------------------------------

OP_ADD: '+';
OP_SUB: '-';
OP_MUL: '*';
OP_DIV: '/';
OP_MOD: '%';

BOOLEAN        : 'true' | 'false' ;
NUMBER         : '-'? INT ;
fragment INT   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]* ;
ID             : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
// ...
```

I'm still not entirely sure on how to implement the `BuildAstVisitor`. I now have something along the lines of the following, but it certainly doesn't look right to me...

```
@Override
public Expr visitMini(MiniCppParser.MiniContext ctx) {
  for (MiniCppParser.ConstDeclContext constDeclCtx : ctx.constDecl()) {
    visit(constDeclCtx);
  }
  return null;
}

@Override
public Expr visitConstDecl(MiniCppParser.ConstDeclContext ctx) {
  visit(ctx.type());
  return visit(ctx.init());
}
```

Comment: You've put a Kleene star `*` around your expression, which means each item can occur any number of times, or never at all. That's why `ctx.constDecl()` returns a list, which contains *all* the `constDecl` child nodes. You can only assign labels to top-level alternative elements (ie `rule: foo # labelA | bar # labelB ;`), that's why ANTLR refuses that. I don't really know what's the solution here since I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but you'll either have to remove that star to get *exactly one* branch to match, or visit each child node instead of just the first one.

Comment: If I were to visit each child node, what would the `visitMini` function return then? In your example you don't have the problem of having to visit a list of `nodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the individual subrules then implement the visitXXX functions for them (`visitConstDecl()`, `visitVarDef()` etc.) instead of the `visitMini()` function. They will only be called if there's really a match for them in the input. Hence you don't need to do any checks for occurences.

Comment: If I implement the visitor, don't I have to visit the nodes myself? I thought the reason to do this is so that I can traverse the CST myself, building an AST from it. Hence, I do need to implement the `visitMini()` function, because it would be the first rule that's entered. Sorry if I got this wrong!

Comment: I found my mistake: I was implementing the `Visitor` rather than extending the `XBaseVisitor`.