# How do I choose a parent node when building an AST in antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following AST:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class AST {
    Token token;             // from which token do we create this node?
    List<AST> children;      // normalized list of children

    public AST() { ; } // for making nil-rooted nodes

    public AST(Token token) { this.token = token; }

    /** Create node from token type; used mainly for imaginary tokens */
    public AST(int tokenType) { this.token = new CommonToken(tokenType); }

    /** external visitors execute the same action for all nodes
     * with same node type while walking
     */
    public int getNodeType() { return token.getType(); }

    public void addChild(AST t) {
        if (children == null) children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(t);
    }
    public void addChildren(AST... nodes) {
        List<AST> asts = new ArrayList<AST>();
        for (AST node : nodes){asts.add(node);}
        for (int i = 0; i < asts.size(); i++) {
            this.addChild(asts.get(i));
        }
    }

    public List<AST> getChildren() { return children; }

    /** to represent flat lists. A list is a subtree w/o a root, which we simulate
     * with a nil root node. A nil node is a node with token == null.
     */
    public boolean isNil() { return token == null; }

    /** Compute string for single node */
    public String toString() {
        String typeName = CLUBParser.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(getNodeType());
        typeName = typeName == null ? token.getText() : typeName;
        return token != null ? "<" +typeName +", '" + token.getText() +"'>": "nil";
    }

    /** Compute string for a whole tree */
    public String toStringTree() {
        if (children == null || children.isEmpty()) return this.toString();

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        if (!isNil()) {
            buf.append('(');
            buf.append(this.toString());
            buf.append(' ');
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            AST t = children.get(i); // normalized (unnamed) children
            if (t != null) {  // Null check
                if (i > 0) buf.append(' ');
                buf.append(t.toStringTree());
            }
        }
        if (!isNil()) buf.append(')');
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

This Grammar:

```
grammar CLUB;

program : setup round turn funcs EOF ;
setup : SETUP LCURLY s=stmts RCURLY ;
round : ROUND LCURLY s=stmts RCURLY ;
turn : TURN '(' CLASSID VARID ')' '{' s=stmts '}'
        | ;
funcs : func+
        | ;
stmts : s1=stmt s2=stmts
        | ;
func : FUNCID '(' tParams ')' '{' stmts '}'
        | FUNCID '(' ')' '{' stmts '}' ;
tParams : tParam ',' tParams;
stmt : INTVAL ';' ;
iterStmt : 'while' '(' expr ')' '{' stmts '}'
        | 'for' '(' decl ';' expr ';' postfExpr ')' '{' stmts '}' ;
selectStmt : 'if' '(' expr ')' '{' stmts '}' ;
exprStmt : expr ;
type : 'bool'
        | 'int'
        | 'string' ;
tParam : type VARID ;
params : param ',' params
        |'['list']' ',' param
        | param ;
list : OBJID ',' list
        | OBJID ;
param : assignExpr ;
expr : assignExpr ;
assignExpr : logicOrExpr
        | primaryExpr '=' assignExpr ;
logicOrExpr : logicAndExpr
        | logicOrExpr '||' logicAndExpr ;
logicAndExpr : equalExpr
        | logicAndExpr '&&' equalExpr ;
equalExpr : relatExpr
        | equalExpr '==' relatExpr
        | equalExpr '!=' relatExpr ;
relatExpr : addExpr
        | relatExpr '<' addExpr
        | relatExpr '>' addExpr
        | relatExpr '<=' addExpr
        | relatExpr '>=' addExpr ;
addExpr : multExpr
        | addExpr '+' multExpr
        | addExpr '-' multExpr ;
multExpr : unaryExpr
        | multExpr '*' unaryExpr
        | multExpr '/' unaryExpr ;
unaryExpr : postfExpr
        | '-' postfExpr
        | '!' postfExpr ;
postfExpr : primaryExpr
        | primaryExpr '++'
        | primaryExpr '--'
        | primaryExpr '(' params ')'
        | primaryExpr '('  ')'
        | METHODID '(' params ')'
        | METHODID '(' ')'
        | primaryExpr '.' postfExpr ;
primaryExpr : val
        | VARID
        | OBJID
        | FUNCID
        | CLASSID ;
val : BOOLVAL
        | INTVAL
        | STRINGVAL  ;
decl : tParam '=' logicOrExpr ;

AND : '&&' ;
OR : '||' ;
EQ : '==' ;
NOTEQ : '!=' ;
SMALLER : '<' ;
LARGER : '>' ;
SMALLEREQ : '<=' ;
BIGGEREQ : '>=' ;
INCREM : '++' ;
DECREM : '--' ;
PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
MULT : '*' ;
DIVIDE : '/' ;
DOT : '.' ;
NOT : '!' ;
ASSIGN : '=' ;
COMMA : ',' ;
SEMI : ';' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
LCURLY : '{' ;
RCURLY : '}' ;
LSQUARE : '[' ;
RSQUARE : ']' ;

WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip ;


SETUP : 'Setup' ;
ROUND : 'Round' ;
TURN : 'Turn' ;
WHILE : 'while' ;
FOR : 'for' ;
IF : 'if' ;
BOOL : 'bool' ;
INT : 'int' ;
STRING : 'string' ;


METHODID : 'create'
        |'getHand'
        |'getHandPoints'
        |'handSize'
        |'printHand'
        |'getTable'
        |'getTablePoints'
        |'printTable'
        |'getDiscardPile'
        |'draw'
        |'discard'
        |'takeCard'
        |'layDown'
        |'addJokers'
        |'assignPoints'
        |'shuffle'
        |'getCard'
        |'getCards'
        |'print'
        |'size'
        |'returnCards'
        |'returnDiscardPile'
        |'flip'
        |'getPoints' ;
BOOLVAL : 'true'
        | 'false' ;
CLASSID : 'Player'
        | 'Deck'
        | 'Card'
        | 'Table' ;
OBJID : [HDCS][2-9]
        |[HDCS]'1'[0-3]?
        |'J'[1-3]
        |'player'[1-9][0-9]*
        |'deck'
        |'table' ;
INTVAL : '0'
        | [1-9][0-9]* ;
VARID : [a-z][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
FUNCID : [A-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
STRINGVAL : '"'~["]*'"' ;
```

And the following overwritten methods that work fine:

```
public class ClubBuildASTVisitor extends CLUBBaseVisitor<AST> {
    // Start of tree
    @Override
    public AST visitProgram(CLUBParser.ProgramContext ctx) {
        AST ast = new AST();
        ast.addChild(visit(ctx.setup()));
        ast.addChild(visit(ctx.round()));
        ast.addChild(visit(ctx.turn()));
        ast.addChild(visit(ctx.funcs()));
        return ast;
    }

    @Override
    public AST visitSetup(CLUBParser.SetupContext ctx) {
        AST ast = new AST(ctx.SETUP().getSymbol());
        ast.addChild(visit(ctx.stmts()));
        return ast;
    }

    @Override
    public AST visitRound(CLUBParser.RoundContext ctx) {
        AST ast = new AST(ctx.ROUND().getSymbol());
        AST stmtsAst = visit(ctx.stmts());
        ast.addChild(stmtsAst);
        return ast;
    }
```

Im trying to create one for visitStmts. The problem is that the when I make one it keeps choosing the first child in the tree to become the root. An example would be:

```
@Override
public AST visitStmts(CLUBParser.StmtsContext ctx) {
    AST ast = new AST(ctx.getStart());
    int childCount = ctx.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        ParseTree child = ctx.getChild(i);
        AST childAst = visit(child);
        ast.addChild(childAst);
    }
    return ast;
}
```

How can i choose Round as my root and make the rest children?

ive tried replacing the parameters of the

```
@Override
public AST visitStmts(CLUBParser.StmtsContext ctx) {
    AST ast = new AST(new CommonToken(CLUBParser.ROUND)); // Create AST with "ROUND" as the root token

    if (ctx.stmt() != null) {
        AST stmtChild = visit(ctx.stmt());
        ast.addChild(stmtChild);
    }

    if (ctx.stmts() != null) {
        AST stmtsChild = visit(ctx.stmts());
        if (stmtsChild != null && !stmtsChild.isNil()) {
            for (AST child : stmtsChild.getChildren()) {
                ast.addChild(child);
            }
        }
    }

    return ast;
}
```

But that ends up with the output looking like this:
`(<SETUP, 'Setup'> (<ROUND, 'null'> )) (<ROUND, 'Round'> (<ROUND, 'null'> ))`

I need the AST for type checking but ive read its also possible to do so with the parse tree built into antlr4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create AST with ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971097/how-to-create-ast-with-antlr4)

Comment: @aled The answer was not quite what I needed, but it gave me the inspiration I needed to fix it and it now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This construct:

```
stmts : s1=stmt s2=stmts
        | ;
stmt : INTVAL ';' ;
```

Will create a parse tree that is n nodes deep where n is the number of `stmt`s, and each level will have its own `stmts` node.  This will make it a bit cumbersome to navigate to the "parent" of the top level `stmts` node.

This is not an uncommon structure in parser generators less expressive than ANTLR.  However, in ANTLR you can get the same ability to parse "one or more `stmt`s" as a `stmts` rule, like so:

```
stmts: stmt+;
```

If you take a look at the Ctx class generated for this rule, you'll find that all of your `stmt`s will be in a list in the `stmts` Ctx.  You won't have to trace up an extended tree to find the root `stmts`'s parent.

You don't provide sample input so it's not easy to provide images of the difference between the parse trees, but you can use the `grun` alias, an ANTLR plugin for your IDE or [Antlr Lab](http://lab.antlr.org) to see the difference in the two parse trees. Take a look at the parse tree with and without the changes, and it should be obvious that using `+` to build the list produces a parse tree that's much more manageable.

This should make it much easier to gather all of the `stmt` nodes that are the children of your `stmts` node (and you'll only have a single `stmts` node that just contains a list of the `stmt` children).

Note:  You may even find, that it simplifies things enough that you can change:

```
setup : SETUP LCURLY s=stmts RCURLY ;
round : ROUND LCURLY s=stmts RCURLY ;
```

to:

```
setup : SETUP LCURLY s=stmt+ RCURLY ;
round : ROUND LCURLY s=stmt+ RCURLY ;
```

and drop the `stmts` rule entirely.